# Why is the transgression of differential forms a form?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

In the nLab page on [transgression of differential forms](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/transgression+of+differential+forms) at definition 2.7 they have

> Let $E \stackrel{\mathrm{fb}}{\rightarrow} \Sigma$ be a field bundle over a spacetime $\Sigma$ (def. 2.5), with induced jet bundle $J_{\Sigma}^{\infty}(E)$.
> For $\Sigma_r \hookrightarrow \Sigma$ be a submanifold of spacetime of dimension $r \in \mathbb{N}$, then *transgression of variational differential forms to $\Sigma_r$* is the function
> $$
> \tau_{\Sigma_r}: \Omega_{\Sigma, \mathrm{cp}}^{r, \bullet}(E) \longrightarrow \Omega^{\bullet}\left(\Gamma_{\Sigma_r}(E)\right)
> $$
> which sends a differential form $A \in \Omega_{\Sigma, \text { cp }}^{r, \bullet}(E)$ to the differential form $\tau_{\Sigma_r} \in \Omega^{\bullet}\left(\Gamma_{\Sigma_r}(E)\right)$ which to a smooth family on field configurations
> $$
> \Phi_{(-)}: U \times N_{\Sigma} \Sigma_r \longrightarrow E
> $$
> assigns the differential form given by first forming the pullback of differential forms along the family of jet prolongation $j_{\Sigma}^{\infty}\left(\Phi_{(-)}\right)$followed by the integration of differential forms over $\Sigma_r$ :
> $$
> \tau_{\Sigma}A_{\Phi_{(-)}}:=\int_{\Sigma_r}\left(j_{\Sigma}^{\infty}\left(\Phi_{(-)}\right)\right)^*A \in \Omega^{\bullet}(U) .
> $$

Why is the last expression a differential form? After integration we have a number  so isn't it a function?

Comment: Every scalar function is a $0$-form, so maybe that is all they mean.

Comment: the $\bullet $ in  $\Omega^{\bullet}(U)$ indicates the dimension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After integration we have a number so isn't it a function?

Differential $k$-forms can be integrated along a submersion with $d$-dimensional fibers, which yields a differential $(k-d)$-form.

Fiberwise integration (alias pushforward) of differential forms is a standard operation, described in many expository texts.  A fairly detailed presentation is given in Chapter VII of

- Werner Greub, Stephen Halperin, Ray Vanstone.  Connections, Curvature, and Cohomology.  Volume I.  [De Rham Cohomology of Manifolds and Vector Bundles](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0079-8169(08)62844-5).  Pure and Applied Mathematics 47A (1972), Academic Press.